# How do I build a comma delimited string om SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a query that returns a reasonable number of records from a table.  I need to include a comma delimited string as an output column.  Something like this

```
SELECT
 column1,
 column2,
 column3,
 [Delimited string based on the id]
FROM
  sometable
WHERE
  id = someid
```

I know you can use the coalesce function which i have used in the past but im not sure how to integrate it into a select statement, also not really sure on the performance?

Any ideas?

Comment: What breed of SQL are you using?  MySQL, SQL-server, Postgres?

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? SQL Server, MySQL?

Comment: @cularis Apologies my bad.  Im using SQLServer 2000

Comment: I'm really unclear of what your comma delimited string should contain. Is it the values from column1, column2 and column3 as a csv string or some other set of values?

Comment: @Steve Weet the delimited string will hold values from a lookup table.

Comment: This link might help get you started: http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-from-a-column-into-a-single-row.html If you want more specific advice as an answer, maybe you could tell us the schema of your lookup table...

Answer (score 0):

I'd loop through the items to build the string with, then add it to the result set.

```
-- Minor performance tweak.
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

-- ID of the item or widget or whatever 
DECLARE @someid int    

DECLARE @LookupItems TABLE
(
    ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    LookupTableID int,          -- Primary key of the lookup table.
    LookupField varchar(30)     -- Text of the lookup value.
)

-- Update to the desired id.
SET @someid = 1234

INSERT INTO @LookupItems (ID, LookupField)
SELECT ID, Value
FROM dbo.somelookuptable
WHERE ID IN (

    SELECT lookupid
    FROM dbo.sometable
    WHERE ID = @someid

)

DECLARE 
    @Count int, 
    @Max int, 
    @DelimitedString varchar(1000)

-- Initialize with a non-NULL value to facilitate concatenation.
SET @DelimitedString = ''  

SET @Count = 1
SELECT @Max = MAX(ID) FROM @LookupItems

WHILE (@Count <= @Max)
BEGIN

    SELECT @DelimitedString = @DelimitedString + IsNull(somefield, '') + ','
    FROM @LookupItems
    WHERE ID = @Count

    SET @Count = @Count + 1

END

SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    @DelimitedString 
FROM dbo.sometable
WHERE id = someid
```